# syntax error on async def while using discord.py

Tags: python, asynchronous, ubuntu-16.04, discord.py

I'm using discord.py on ubuntu 16.04 and on my first virtual device all code works perfectly. Then I moved the same code to a more permanent device, and also there everything works fine, until today... for some reason I keep getting a syntax error  on the "async def" function. This also got marked as error on my test environment (virtual box) but I could always run the code anyway.

I'm using python 3.5 and using python 3.6 also gives the same error.

another thing I can point out is the fact that "@client.event" is fully highlighted on ubuntu in my virtual device, but on the device that does not run the code, only "@client" is highlighted, maybe this says something about the error?

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")

client.run(Token)
```

I also have a async def on_message but I don't think the problem lies within the code as it does run in my virtual box.

Comment: You're using an old syntax checker.  The `async def` syntax was added in Python 3.5.  What editor are you using that you're seeing this error on?  This is syntactically valid python, and a correct `discord.py` program.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I use Geany 1.33 as code editor on the device on which it doesn't work and Geany 1.27 on the one where the codes work. I run the code through the terminal so I'm not sure if the editor causes the problem?

Comment: Can you run the code, or are you getting a SyntaxError when trying to run it?  This shouldn't raise any errors from the python interpreter.

Comment: On one device it only gives the error in the editor, running it through the terminal goes fine, but on another device I can't run it, the console prints the syntax error

Comment: Double check the python version of the failing system.  You're probably accidentally using an older python interpreter.

Comment: I run the code through ~$ python 3 /directory and when I put "import sys" and "print(sys.version)" it also prints out 3.5.2 :/

Comment: My apologies, I feel stupid. After hours of switching codes between computers it was just a forgotten ")" at the end of the previous statement... Thanks for the help anyways!